# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (log content included)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just got started with obj-c Xcode and iPhone development...

I have read that the SIGABRT error is a crash, an uncaught expectation and I need to look trough the log to correct it but I don't know how to do it

Log:

```
2014-05-28 14:25:55.492 ctpp[558:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xaa8b870 ​                </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/    SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle>     (not loaded)
2014-05-28 14:25:55.550 ctpp[558:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x8cbc260> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:     this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key elso.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
​0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f31e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015728e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01882fe1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x01232d9e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)     setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x0119f1d7 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
5   Foundation                          0x0119e731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)     setValue:forKey:] + 267
6   Foundation                          0x01200b0a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)     setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x004e91f4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection     connect] + 106
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015847de -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
9   CoreFoundation                      0x017ee76a -[NSArray     makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
10  UIKit                               0x004e7d4d -[UINib     instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
11  UIKit                               0x003506f5 -[UIViewController     _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
12  UIKit                               0x00350e9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
13  UIKit                               0x003510d3 -[UIViewController     loadViewIfRequired] + 78
14  UIKit                               0x003515d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
15  UIKit                               0x00271267 -[UIWindow     addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
16  UIKit                               0x002715ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] +     312
17  UIKit                               0x0027186b -[UIWindow     _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
18  UIKit                               0x0dc6a587 -    [UIWindowAccessibility(SafeCategory) _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 77
19  UIKit                               0x0027c3c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
20  UIKit                               0x0022cbc0 -[UIApplication     _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
​21  UIKit                               0x00231667 -[UIApplication     _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
22  UIKit                               0x00245f92 -[UIApplication     handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
23  UIKit                               0x00246555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
24  UIKit                               0x00233250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
25  GraphicsServices                    0x037e8f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
26  GraphicsServices                    0x037e8a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0176eca5     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
​28  CoreFoundation                      0x0176e9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
29  CoreFoundation                      0x0179968c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
​30  CoreFoundation                      0x017989d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
31  CoreFoundation                      0x017987eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
32  UIKit                               0x00230d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
33  UIKit                               0x00232f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
34  ctpp                                0x00005bcd main + 141
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e3a701 start + 1
36  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: How are you loading your first view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part closely:

```
reason: '[<ViewController 0x8cbc260> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:     this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key elso.'
```

Somewhere you are using the key 'elso'. Is this the right key or a typo? Looks like a weird key to me, it doesn't tell me anything about the value it points to.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, had an IBOutlet UIPickerView elso and I referenced the typo outlet

Comment: This happened to me all the time when I started.. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you!